# Detect Scroll and Tap in WebView blocks the scroll in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a `WebView` with `UIViewRepresentable` in SwiftUI, and I want to get the coordinates of the touch and the swipe (scroll). But the problem is, that if I try to get the coordinates, the scroll is disabled for the website in the `WebView`, is like blocking the gesture for the UIKit Wrapper. What is happening under the hood for this behaviour and which will be the way to solve it? Because otherwise the code works perfect.

The `SwiftUI` code:

```
struct TaskSwipeGesture: View {
    
    let urlWeb: String = "https://www.google.com/?client=safari"
    
    var body: some View {
        WebView(url: urlWeb)
            .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .local)
                        .onChanged({ value in
                print("Change: X Coordinate is: \(value.location.x), Y Coordinate is: \(value.location.y)")
            })
                        .onEnded({ value in
                print("Ended: X Coordinate is: \(value.location.x), Y Coordinate is: \(value.location.y)")
            })
            )
    }
}
```

The `WebView` wrapper:

```
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let url: String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some WKWebView {
        return WKWebView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
        uiView.load(request)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you use `simultaneousGesture` instead of `gesture`?

Comment: No, it also does not work

Comment: i've created a file with just your code and it works fine in iOS15 simulator Xcode13.2.1, you may want to setup the same and check again. Otherwise you can always handle event the UIKit way with `webView.scrollView.delegate`

Comment: You were able to scroll, navigate and interact with the website?

Comment: oh right, the WebView lost interaction after that, so using UIScrollView is the way then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle event the UIKit way with `webView.scrollView.delegate`

First you need to create `ScrollViewDelegate`

```
class MyScrollViewDelegate: NSObject {
    weak var webView: WKWebView?
}

extension MyScrollViewDelegate: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        printLocation(for: scrollView, label: "will begin dragging")
    }

    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(
        _ scrollView: UIScrollView,
        withVelocity velocity: CGPoint,
        targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>)
    {
        printLocation(for: scrollView, label: "will end dragging")
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView.isTracking {
            printLocation(for: scrollView, label: "is tracking")
        }
    }
    
    private func printLocation(for scrollView: UIScrollView, label: String) {
        if let webView = webView {
            print("\(label) \(scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.location(in: webView))")
        }
    }
}
```

Then apply it into your `WebView` wrapper

```
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let url: String
    let scrollViewDelegate = MyScrollViewDelegate()

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some WKWebView {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        scrollViewDelegate.webView = webView
        webView.scrollView.delegate = scrollViewDelegate
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
        uiView.load(request)
    }
}
```

After that, the `ContentView` will be something like this

```
struct TaskSwipeGesture: View {
    let urlWeb: String = "https://www.google.com/?client=safari"
    var body: some View {
        WebView(url: urlWeb)
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost work!, It does gives you a coordinate, but is the scoordinate INSIDE the web page (x and y, both of them). I need the coordinated of the screen, not from the website

Comment: i've updated my answer, please check if it's what you need

Comment: That made the trick, thank a lot! :)

Comment: how do you know in TaskSwipeGesture view about scrolling position? it doesn't seem to have any reference to MyScrollViewDelegate

Comment: `@State` & `@Binding`